# NoSuchElementException in request

Tags: java, vector, httprequest, enumeration

After the first call to `getHeaders()`, the pointer stays at end of Enumeration en. Second time when `getHeaders()` is called, the and when `while(en.hasMoreElements())` is checked, there are no elements and so empty vector is returned.

```
public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String Pname) {

        Vector<String> s = new Vector<String>();
        Enumeration<String> en = getHttpServletRequest().getHeaders(Pname);
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String data= (String) en.nextElement();
            String erase= remove(data);
           s.add(erase);
        }   

        return s.elements();    
}
```

Exception:

```
   java.util.NoSuchElementException: Vector Enumeration at
   java.util.Vector$1.nextElement(Vector.java:305)
```

Comment: What did you mean with "Second time when getHeaders() is called"? Can you explain it exaclty?

Comment: The code is actually implemented in filter class, whenever the request is processed with header i should get the referer url.In first call , I got the referer as expected . but when i tried to display the value in JSP with the above JSP code , I got the exception since the en has been itreated in while loop in the first call itself.

Comment: You could change your `getHeaders()` method to always return at least one value - see my edited answer for a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `request.getHeaders("referer").nextElement()` will fail if the request has no `referer`. The referer header is not required, and in fact is specifically [not supposed to be used in some circumstances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Referer_hiding).

You could use this code instead:

```
<% Enumeration<String> en = getHttpServletRequest().getHeaders("referer");
   if (en.hasMoreElements()) {
%>
<%= en.nextElement(); %>
<% } %>
```

Another solution would be to change your `getHeaders()` method to always return at least one element in the enumeration:

```
public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {

    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    Enumeration<String> en = getHttpServletRequest().getHeaders(name);
    if (!en.hasMoreElements()) {
        v.add("");
    } else while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String value = (String) en.nextElement();
        String clean = removeXSS(value);
        v.add(clean);
    }   

    return v.elements();    
}
```

Comment: But without implementing the getheaders() ,In JSP i used get null value instead of throwing NosuchElementException.

Comment: To keep that behavior, add at least one element to the enumeration in your custom `getHeaders()` method. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 0):

If your getHeaders() call returns no hits then nextElement() will throw the NoSuchElementException since it is a result with 0 elements and you are already at the end.

This probably means that there was no "referer" header set.

Comment: I understood the getheaders() functionality but , How do i findout the second element or how do i make a second call from JSP without throwing Nosuchelement exception

Comment: i'd probably just use a "for each" loop instead of calling the iterator directly. That way you would be able to handle empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Before you invoke nextElement() you should have a check:

```
<%if (request.getHeaders("referer").hasMoreElements()) { %>
<%=request.getHeaders("referer").nextElement()%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: I have checked please look my code while loop. The issue occurs when i m calling second time in from JSP page